# Replace the url parameter value using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL like below.

```
something.com/TaskHandler/search.do?action=search&category=basic&page=1&sortBy=NAME&Ascending=true&showHiddenElements=false
```

I want to replace the value of parameter `showHiddenElements` to some new value.

for e.g. exising value in URL -> `showHiddenElements=false`

I want to change it through JavaScript to -> `showHiddenElements=true`

Please advise.

Edit: 
`showHiddenElements` may not always be `false`. And In some cases it may not be available.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method

Comment: Can you just use String replace method ?

Comment: `showHiddenElements` may not always be `false`. Or it may not be available at all

Comment: What values can it be? If it's not available do we add it with the value `true`? If it's always going to be true why can't you just ignore it and assume it's true?

Comment: it can be `true` or `false`. If its not available, we just need to add a new one as `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the URL Object:

```
const url = new URL('http://something.com/TaskHandler/search.do?action=search&category=basic&page=1&sortBy=NAME&Ascending=true&showHiddenElements=false');
url.searchParams.delete('showHiddenElements');
url.searchParams.append('showHiddenElements', true);
```

So you just delete the parameter and update it with the new one (not the most elegant)
Docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/URL

Answer (score 1):

You could use `String.replace` for that:

```
var url = 'something.com/TaskHandler/search.do?action=search&category=basic&page=1&sortBy=NAME&Ascending=true&showHiddenElements=false';

newUrl = url.replace('showHiddenElements=false', 'showHiddenElements=true');
```

You could also do it fancy and use regex:

```
var url = 'something.com/TaskHandler/search.do?action=search&category=basic&page=1&sortBy=NAME&Ascending=true&showHiddenElements=false';

newUrl = url.replace(/showHiddenElements=false$/, 'showHiddenElements=true');
```

The regex would only match `showHiddenElements=false` if it's on the end of the URL

To see if it's available you could use regex too:

```
var url = 'something.com/TaskHandler/search.do?action=search&category=basic&page=1&sortBy=NAME&Ascending=true&showHiddenElements=false';

// If the url doesn't have a showHiddenElements=__any_word__
if (!url.match(/showHiddenElements=\w+/)) {
    url = url + 'showHiddenElements=false';
}
```

Comment: `showHiddenElements` may not always be `false`. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Edited the answer to include a if

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = "something.com/TaskHandler/search.do?action=search&category=basic&page=1&sortBy=NAME&Ascending=true&showHiddenElements=false";
alert("Before: "+url);
url = url.replace("&showHiddenElements=false","&showHiddenElements=true");
alert("After: "+url);
//Console.log clips the end so we can't see the result :(
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something liket this:

```
var loc = window.location.href;
var newLoc = loc.Replace('showHiddenElements=true', 'showHiddenElements=false')
```

Comment: 1. It's lowercase and 2. The arguments are reversed

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript Regular Expression should help if you are just treating the URL as a string.

```
var str = 'something.com/TaskHandler/search.do?action=search&category=basic&page=1&sortBy=NAME&Ascending=true&showHiddenElements=false';

var res = str.replace(/showHiddenElements/i, 'true');

console.log(res);
```